# How to mock a template class with gmock (Google Mock)?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates, mocking, googlemock

I have a class template as following:

```
struct DailyQuote_t;
struct TickQuote_t;

template <typename Q>
class QtBuffer_t {
public:
   virtual int size() const noexcept = 0;
};
```

When testing another class named OrderBook_t, the instances QtBuffer_t<DailyQuote_t> and QtBuffer_t<TickQuote_t> are both required.

```
class OrderBook_t {
public:
   void setDependent( const QtBuffer_t<DailyQuote_t>* pDB, const QtBuffer_t<TickQuote_t>* pTB ) noexcept {
      m_pDBuf = pDB;
      m_pTBuf = pTB;
   };

   bool update() {
      m_pDBuf->size();
      m_pTBuf->size();
   };

private:
   const QtBuffer_t<DailyQuote_t>* m_pDBuf;
   const QtBuffer_t<TickQuote_t>*  m_pTBuf;
};
```

I tried to mock the template as following, but I failed:

```
template<typename Q>
class QtBufferMock : public QtBuffer_t<Q> {
public:
   MOCK_METHOD( int, size, (), ( const, noexcept, override ) );
};
```

Finally I have to mock them respectively:

```
class DailyBufferMock : public QtBuffer_t<DailyQuote_t> {
public:
   MOCK_METHOD( int, size, (), ( const, noexcept, override ) );
};

class TickBufferMock : public QtBuffer_t<TickQuote_t> {
public:
   MOCK_METHOD( int, size, (), ( const, noexcept, override ) );
};
```

Is there a way we can mock a class template with single mock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well by looking at the cook_book https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md you can in fact do it. It might be interesting maybe to check if you are using the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I read the cook book you offered, but I think that the way in that URL is same with mine, i.e. "to mock them respectively", not "mock them with single one template". Am I right?

Comment: I think you can do it with one single template as well.
You can check the example in the section ```Mocking Class Templates```, but I guess that you will need to check the version in which they added this feature, or maybe do a prior test in a dedicated folder to make sure everything works properly. It's difficult for me to assess your issue as long I don't have a proper compilation error, unfortunately. I assume as their are no any particular issues regarding this problem in the repository, that there is no bug.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried it out, it works. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Running your code verbatim on an example test works for me:

```
template<typename Q>
class QtBufferMock : public QtBuffer_t<Q> {
public:
   MOCK_METHOD( int, size, (), ( const, noexcept, override ) );
};


TEST(T1, CreateMockObj){
    QtBufferMock<DailyQuote_t> m1;
    QtBufferMock<TickQuote_t> m2;
    OrderBook_t t;
    t.setDependent(&m1,&m2); 
    t.update();
}
```

On commit dcc92d0ab6c4ce022162a23566d44f673251eee4 (April 2020), which is past the [latest release](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases/latest). As afkid, I wonder if you are using a recent enough version of `gmock`?

Comment: Thank you very much, but I must accept afkid's answer because his answer is earlier.